# Do the USA and France offer tax havens?

Tags: taxes, corruption

- ['Stolen assets of developing countries must be returned,' PM Imran tells UN panel](https://www.dawn.com/news/1581386)

Prime Minister Imran Khan called upon the international community to take steps to counter illicit flows of money, saying the "stolen assets" of developing countries must be returned.

- [British ‘Treasure Island’ tax havens face a tempest](https://www.reuters.com/business/finance/british-treasure-island-tax-havens-face-tempest-2021-06-07/#:%7E:text=British%20tax%20havens%20are%20responsible,tax%20abuse%20on%20the%20planet.)

The UK has three tax havens:

1. British Virgin Island
2. Cayman Island
3. Bermuda

Politicians, oligarchs, and frauds of poor countries stash their illegally earned or embezzled money in these places and their respective governments are unable to touch them or prove the crime.

- [How Britain's Bankers Made Billions From The End Of Empire](https://youtu.be/-YgFDZNXPyg)

Also, when asked about these havens' roles in aiding frauds from all over the world, the UK government denies any responsibility saying that they can't do anything as those islands have their own local laws, local governments, etc.

Do the USA and France offer similar tax havens?

Comment: There's Cyprus but it also has large british influence.

Comment: A simple search for tax heavens brought: https://www.worlddata.info/tax-havens.php Also the title question and the question body question aren't the same. Are you interested in general tax heavens or just in tax heavens that also belong in some way to France or the US?

Comment: @Trilarion please note the spelling: _haven,_ meaning "harbor," not _heaven,_ meaning "paradise."

Comment: *Are you interested in general tax heavens or just in tax heavens that also belong in some way to France or the US?* --- their own territory. Also, not only tax havens, but also those havens that help people hide their money.

Comment: And now the question is how this is related to politics? As it is, it might be more suitable for money.stackexchange.com. What do we learn about politics from looking up tax havens (thanks phoog) from France and the US?

Comment: Weird no answer have mentioned Delaware yet. At least for American companies pulling profit out of the EU then for over 90% (maybe old number) it goes via. Luxembourg to a company registered in Delaware.

Comment: @Trilarion The possibility for dictators to stash away huge sums of stolen money abroad is one ingredient in what makes governance so abysmal for so many in poor countries.   Not sure what France and the US, specifically, have to do with this phenomenon, but the larger question remains in to what extent the West is complicit with enabling dictatorships.  Which is quite political in nature.

Comment: The only way I think the British government could influence these territories tax haven status is to forbid any company or fund with a UK office from doing business there. But I think that's unlikely to happen because it's a lose/lose situation for both parties, the UK's financial service sector would take a major hit, with family offices leaving in droves (London is a very attractive location for them), and these caribbean nations would be deprived of pretty much the only thing that makes them wealthy compared to many of their impoverished neighbours.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica " Not sure what France and the US, specifically, have to do with this phenomenon.." That's exactly what I was asking for in a comment. I don't understand what about what political issue this question about France and the US is about.

Comment: @Trilarion, coz, the USA and France are the permanent members of the UNSC.

Comment: True, but so is the UK and Russia and China. What has it to do with tax havens. I just want something spelled out in the question that tells what the issue is with France and the US and tax havens.

Comment: @phoog Strange, because the Czech translation "[daňový ráj](https://cs.wikipedia.org/wiki/Da%C5%88ov%C3%BD_r%C3%A1j)" literally says "tax paradise". Similarly in Polish or, if I understand it correctly, even in Spanish.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава interesting.  French Wiktionary suggests that _paradis fiscal_ may arise from a confused mistranslation from English, but given how much more prevalent the sense of "paradise" is in other languages, this seems a bit unlikely.  Did they all take the term from French or mistranslate it independently?  Perhaps the imprecise translation was intentional in some cases, if the figurative use of words for "port," "harbor," or "haven" is rare in some language.  My (superficial) research does show that the term arose earlier in English than in French or German, at least.

Comment: @ThomasKoelle Corporations register in Delaware not so much because of being a "tax haven," as because it has [a modern and highly predictable corporate legal system](https://whyy.org/articles/why-do-so-many-corporations-choose-to-incorporate-in-delaware/).

Comment: @reirab Delaware is also the only jurisdiction in the U.S. that authorizes companies and trusts to waive 100% of the fiduciary duties of the people who management them.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To my knowledge, France does not offer any form of tax haven, as opposed to the US and the UK. However French people who want to hide their assets don't need to travel very far: traditionally [Switzerland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banking_in_Switzerland#Connection_to_illegal_activities) was a destination of choice for banking secrecy, but [Luxembourg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luxembourg#Economy) and [Liechtenstein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liechtenstein#Taxation) were not far behind. Additionally the principalities of [Monaco](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monaco) and [Andorra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andorra) offer very moderate tax rates.

*[Complement about the US added later]*

The US is not traditionally considered a tax haven, even though several states have lax legislation: [Delaware](https://www.nytimes.com/2012/07/01/business/how-delaware-thrives-as-a-corporate-tax-haven.html) is often cited, but also Nevada, Montana, South Dakota, Wyoming and New York. Recently the US adopted legislation ([the Foreign Account Tax Compliance Act (FATCA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_Account_Tax_Compliance_Act)) which requires foreign institutions to transmit information about US entities to the US Treasury, i.e. to fight tax evasion *from the US*. However the US refuses to reciprocate by sending information about foreign entities in the US to foreign countries, in effect making [the US a tax haven](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/wonk/wp/2016/04/05/how-the-u-s-became-one-of-the-worlds-biggest-tax-havens/) for foreign entities.

Comment: Which tax havens do the US have?

Comment: @Trilarion: The US has one of the most permissive legislation, doesn't share information with other countries (although they expect other countries to share information with them) and is consequently used as a tax haven ([Wkipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_as_a_tax_haven)).

Comment: @Erwan Tax haven in this question is more hiding. There is no hiding stolen assets. This was done away in the 60s with tax evasion being prosecuted. Taxes will be paid.

Comment: @paulj I'm not sure I understand your point. You're probably referring to taxes owed to the US, but the US is a tax haven for entities from other countries.

Comment: None of those states escape U.S. federal taxation, and NY State has high state taxes as well. NV, MT, SD, WY and AK have tried without much success with favorable asset protection laws but can't escape U.S. income taxation. Puerto Rico can offer respite from U.S. federal taxes, but Commonwealth taxes aren't all that low.

Comment: @ohwilleke I'm certainly not as knowledgeable as you about the topic, but I think there is a misunderstanding: you're talking about federal taxation *by the US treasury*, whereas my answer addresses entities hiding assets in the US which are *taxable by non-US countries*. In this sense the US is considered a tax haven.

Comment: @Erwan Typically when you talk about a tax haven you reduce your total taxes owed dramatically from the country where they would "naturally" be owed without planning, but typically relocating assets from a foreign country to the U.S. only modestly reduces total taxes because U.S. taxes aren't that much lower than taxes in the countries where taxes are avoided. Simply putting assets in any U.S. jurisdiction without a state income tax can achieve that end, no haven required.

Comment: @ohwilleke My understanding is that individuals or companies would transfer money to a state with lax banking laws, then either buy some asset or re-transfer the funds somewhere else through various shell companies in order to avoid any income tax in the US as well.

Answer (score 7):

There is no fixed list of tax havens. Those countries continuously implement new rules that promise more transparency and obtain the exclusion from the official list. But then the finance experts find new ways to circumvent the rules, often the architects of these systems work from London or Wall Street, there is the best expertise involved.

Furthermore some places like [Dubai](https://www.aljazeera.com/economy/2021/3/9/uae-is-among-the-worlds-fastest-growing-tax-havens-study-finds) or even some [US states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_as_a_tax_haven) are not in the list.

Anyway you may want to take a look at this [list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tax_haven#Broad_lists_of_tax_havens), you might notice that when you listed the British tax havens you forgot the Isle of Man and Gibraltar. What about Jersey? Even that list is always changing.

**Update:**
I noticed that the title of the question was changed. Anyway the answer by @Erwan tells only part of the story. France has a sophisticated financial system, rich French people are probably clients of most of the tax havens you can find around. [Luxembourg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luxembourg#Economy) and the [Netherlands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tax_haven#OECD%E2%80%93IMF_(1998%E2%80%932018)) are mainly used by those entrepreneurs who need an umbrella company within the EU to shift the profit of their businesses, like [Ireland does for Apple](https://ec.europa.eu/commission/presscorner/detail/en/IP_16_2923). All the other tax havens are used more to hide private wealth.

**Update 2** @Trilarion comment:
The situation of Monaco is ambiguous. Financial institutions there, to my knowledge, do not do so much to help rich people to hide their wealth. If someone want to live in another country and pay their taxes there it is not illegal. However if someone takes a residence in a country, but then conducts most of their life and business in another country they are committing a tax fraud, but in this case the responsibility is more of the individual than the host country.

Comment: I was really curious about France.

Comment: @user366312 Maybe you mean French rich people and companies as beneficiaries of tax haven. As far as I know France has never been a provider of tax havens.

Comment: *Maybe you mean French rich people and companies as beneficiaries of the tax haven.* --- I know, they use Luxembourg.

Comment: @user366312 I noticed just now that now that the title of your question was changed. Anyway the accepted answer tells only part of the story. France has a sophisticated financial system, rich French people are probably clients of most of the tax havens you can find around. Luxembourg and the Netherlands are mainly used by those entrepreneurs who need an umbrella company within the EU to shift the profit of their businesses, like Ireland does for Apple. All the other tax havens are used more to hide private wealth.

Comment: What about Monaco? It seems to be a tax haven and it's really close to France. If I would be a super rich French citizen I might want to bring my money there or to Switzerland maybe too?

Answer (score 3):

### US Definitely

https://www.washingtonpost.com/business/interactive/2021/booming-us-tax-haven-industry/

https://foreignpolicy.com/2021/11/19/delaware-illicit-finance-corruption-offshore-wealth-american-kleptocracy-book-excerpt/

https://www.cbsnews.com/news/pandora-papers-tax-haven-south-dakota/

https://www.morningbrew.com/daily/stories/2021/10/08/how-south-dakota-became-one-of-the-biggest-tax-havens-in-the-world

https://inequality.org/research/the-united-states-of-tax-havens/

Unlike the other countries in the question, this happens in normal US states, not quasi-foreign territories, but only a few like Delaware and South Dakota are offenders and it's done through trusts, not banking secrecy, but in absolute terms, the US is a top-tier international tax-haven.

### France?

I haven't encountered any information about France serving as a tax haven, this may be because it doesn't, or because of the lack of English sources on the subject.

Comment: write something on france, plz.

Comment: @user366312 I haven't read about France being a tax haven, the way I have about the US. Updated the answer to reflect that.

Comment: No U.S. state offers shelter from U.S. federal income taxes which are not tax haven low. Calling these tax havens is an exaggeration.

Comment: @ohwilleke did you even read any article I linked? E.g. from the CBS article: " the United States is now ranked as the world's No. 2 tax haven by the Tax Justice Network, sheltering more money than any other except for the Cayman Islands". US trusts may be leery of the IRS, but are quite happy to hide the dubious wealth of non-americans from around the world and trusts are exempt from taxes by themselves. Analogously, Swiss banks never helped Swiss citizens evade Swiss taxes. And within the US, trusts hide money from creditors, child support, alimony, etc.

Comment: @ohwilleke from the Foreignpolicy article: Viktor Bout, the Russian arms dealer that the movie "Lord of War" is about, didn't park his blood money in Switzerland, or Bermuda, the Cayman Islands, or any one of the other usual suspects, but in a trust in the US State of Delaware, hidden behind Delaware shell companies(another "local specialty").

Comment: @Eugene I don't disagree that trusts are used to hide money (commonly called "asset protection"). But the notion that "trusts are exempt from taxes by themselves" is inaccurate except in cases not applicable here like charitable trusts.

Comment: @ohwilleke I'm not a tax lawyer and I only know what I've come across on the subject, but it looks like some sorts of trusts have no tax liability for the trust itself. I did a quick lookup and came across: https://www.fidelity.com/viewpoints/wealth-management/insights/trusts-and-taxes there, out of the 4 trust types examined, only the complex trust has the tax liability as "Trust and/or beneficiary(s)", for the other types, it's either grantor or beneficiaries. It looks like if neither the grantor nor the beneficiaries have US tax liabilities, there are not US taxes to be paid.

Comment: @ohwilleke and since the trusts hide the money from foreign tax collectors, there are no taxes paid period. Every article says that the trusts help avoid taxes, e.g "According to one example from the South Dakota Trust Company, $5 million placed into a trust for 120 years, and growing at a conservative rate of 6% a year, would balloon to $5.4 billion at the end of that time period. If it were given as a gift outright, without a trust and subject to taxes, its value would be a comparatively smaller $340 million."

Comment: @ohwilleke: The thing is that the term "tax heaven" is alas used to denote both non-hidden "heavens" where companies like Google process their corporate income (Ireland etc.)  where corpora income taxes are low and places that don't necessarily have the lowest taxes (like London) but where a lot of money is hidden in real estate etc. because finding the actual owner isn't easy. South Dakota has no state estate taxes, but one would have to pay federal US taxes on most things, so Google isn't parking money in South Dakota.

Comment: @Fizz Google wouldn't hide it's money in South Dakota, because it's an American company and would get reported to the IRS, but foreign companies can. The US has forced financial institutions in other countries to report on US citizens and corporations through FATCA, but that's a one way street, those countries don't get data from the US and the US is outside of CRS(the other reporting agreement), so US based trusts in states with high confidentiality are used for full on tax evasion(not avoidance which is what Google does).

Comment: @Fizz e.g. an Indonesian businessman buys stock from Thailand for his business through a shell company that's owned by a Delaware trust he controls. Half the money goes to the supplier(the real cost) and half is kept by the trust, to make it look like the deal barely broke even and he pays no taxes, because his company is doing badly and not making a profit. And it's completely secret from the Indonesian government and the IRS doesn't care because he's not American.

Answer (score 2):

[united-states](/questions/tagged/united-states)

This answer is limited to the U.S., where I have taught and practiced in this area, since I don't know much about French law in this area.

The bottom line, is that there aren't really full fledged tax havens in then U.S., although some U.S. states provide a fair amount of protection from creditors of the person forming a trust there. Asset protection and tax reduction are two distinct goals of "havens" and U.S. jurisdictions only do much for the former, not the latter.

A numbers of states, such as South Dakota, Wyoming, Nevada, Delaware, and Alaska have relaxed traditional rules that disfavor "dynasty trusts" designed to allow trusts to endure with "dead hand" control for many generations.

These states also impose only modest state taxes on trust and shell company assets (Delaware charges rather high flat fees for setting up entities there but not a tax based upon the amount of assets the entity formed there holds, or its profits.)

And, perhaps most importantly, these states have put in place strong protections for trust assets from creditors' claims and allow high levels of privacy for firms and trusts established there. Federal law anti-money laundering laws, some of which were due to take effect on January 1, 2022 but have been delayed due to delays in adopting implementing regulations, also require significant disclosures of entity ownership, undermining this historic benefit of these U.S. jurisdictions.

But none of that shields assets in these states from federal income taxation, which while hardly the highest among developed countries (U.S. corporate tax rates, in particular, were cut dramatically starting in the 2018 tax year), is also nowhere near the low rates of traditional "tax havens" like the Cayman Island and Nevis (these island nations typically finance their governmental operations primarily with customs duties and user fees).

This is why many big U.S. multinational technology companies try to locate much of their intangible "hot asset" profits from their intellectual property rights and financial investments in jurisdictions like Ireland, instead of the U.S.

It is possible in many cases for businesses based in Puerto Rico to be free of federal income taxation, but only in exchange for paying significant Commonwealth of Puerto Rico taxes. And Puerto Rico has not adopted laws that make itself attractive as a creditor-protection haven.

So, while some U.S. states are taxed at favorable rates relative to other U.S. jurisdictions and provide some asset protection, it isn't at the extreme levels associated with foreign asset protection and tax havens like Luxembourg, Switzerland, the Cayman Islands, and Nevis.

The efficacy of these protections is also overstated.

For example, I am familiar with a case where someone attempted to use South Dakota entities and trusts to shield significant assets from an IRS tax creditor and this effort failed dismally.

The option of an involuntary bankruptcy case or federal securities fraud claims can also often pierce domestic asset protection trusts and entities. And, U.S. judges are not reluctant to incarcerate debtors with associated asset protection trusts that U.S. judges believe that the debtors have a *de facto* ability to access for many years, in rare cases in excess of a decade.

On the other hand, while these jurisdictions in the U.S. offer only half-measures of protection, they do provide people relying on them with low levels of corruption in administering their hidden assets, and an ability to enforce their own rights in a relatively predictable and reliable legal system.

Another point worth keeping in mind is that many famous tax havens invest their assets in the U.S. securities market as non-resident foreign corporations controlled by foreign persons and not affiliated with U.S. persons.

For example, a Cayman Islands trust with a Cayman Island's trustee and Columbian beneficiaries can invest in companies traded on the New York Stock exchange without being subject to U.S. taxes on the dividends and capital gains that the Cayman Islands trust earns on those investments.

This is something that a company or trust organized under the law of a U.S. state cannot do, because U.S. entities are subject to U.S. income tax on their worldwide income. A parallel U.S. federal income tax regime also imposes high U.S. taxes on "Controlled Foreign Corporations" that are beneficially owned by U.S. persons even though they are organized abroad.

Comment: Probably the only good answer to this Q, but as I have come to expect on politics SE, any question related to economics gets votes in proportionality with the superficiality of the answers.