# How can developing and underdeveloped countries get out of the arm-twisting cycle?

Tags: western-world

- [Contents of letter carrying 'evidence of foreign conspiracy' against govt shared with journalists](https://www.dawn.com/news/1682562/contents-of-letter-carrying-evidence-of-foreign-conspiracy-against-govt-shared-with-journalists)

According to the above article:

> They showed the letter from a distance. It is very clearly evident [from the letter] that whatever is happening in Pakistan through the no-confidence motion was conveyed on March 7 and [whoever the letter was addressed to] was told that if the vote of no-confidence is successful, Pakistan's problems internationally will be reduced but if Prime Minister Imran Khan survives the no-confidence vote, arm-twisting of Pakistan will be done.

also

> "What they shared with us is that this letter is a conversation between Pakistani officials and officials of another country. According to my understanding, that country is America but the government did not name the country. They did not tell the number of officials or the location of the meeting. They said that Europe and the US are not happy with Pakistan's stance on Russia and Ukraine."

- [PM Imran Khan revealed secret letter threatening to oust his Govt](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PMzSjA-42Y4)

According to the above Urdu vlog of a Pakistani journalist, PM Imran Khan called them to show the portion of an official document of records of a visit of Pakistani officials to a foreign country. During this visit, the Pakistani officials were conveyed a message that -

> the administration of the foreign country is not happy with the Pakistani PM's policies, especially regarding Russia. Therefore, the PM has to go. There is a no-confidence motion coming up against him, and if he survives, Pakistan will face a grim future.

While PM Imran Khan was showing the evidence to the journalists, he also told them that, the actual language from the document was derogatory and threatening at the same time which PM cannot reveal because of the Pakistani secrecy act.

**The most important part of this incident is, this meeting was held on 7th March when there were no talks of no-confidence from the opposition. This means that this no-confidence motion was arranged by that foreign administration.**

[image]

[image]

In the above photo, a US embassy official is seen reading out instructions to opposition MPAs.

By the way, this is not the first time this is happening in Pakistan. The foreign powers have [a history of actively interfering with Pakistan's internal affairs](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2006/sep/22/pakistan.usa).

[image]

This is an example of how powerful and rich countries in the West arm twist poorer countries to achieve their own objectives, and the poorer countries have to sacrifice their sovereignty.

How can developing and underdeveloped countries get out of the arm-twisting cycle?

Comment: I'm sorry but how is this not a crazy conspiracy? So as I understand that article, there supposedly was some covert US plan against the Pakistani government and the evidence for this is a letter which then made it to the very people the plan was supposed to undermine? To be honest, I don't think this is really answerable because we don't know what the alleged plan is or if it's even real.

Comment: I believe what @FluidCode was misinterpreting was the term “survives” as in “lives through” instead of “retains his position after”, thereby asking the question of why he would be killed. I can’t speak to the “a man so useful for their interests” part of the comment

Comment: The main question is how can it be proved that he letter was from any foreign country and not fabricated by one of them?

Answer (score 1):

**There is no right to be traded with, or to be liked.**

In an interconnected global society, countries trade, people visit, and that makes absolute sovereignty a theoretical notion. We have become used to a world where most nations have relations which go beyond the minimum between sovereign nations, but going beyond that minimum is **not a right**. In a way, one of the most sovereign nations is the [DPRK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Economy_of_North_Korea), and look what it got them.

Look at the EU rule of law controversy, and how Poland was [pressured](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_constitutional_crisis) to uphold EU standards by the threat of **withholding** money with the Polish government considered their due. For that matter, there are international [political parties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_political_party) in the EU, and foreigners actually come and **campaign** in national elections of neighbouring states. The fights about the [EU budget](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Budget_of_the_European_Union) are vicious, too. Or look at the [new Afghan government](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Islamic_Emirate_of_Afghanistan_(1996%E2%80%932001)), which found that the West wouldn't **donate** them the same sums the previous government got. This can go the other way, too. When the Somali government [helped](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lufthansa_Flight_181#Aftermath) Germany with an aircraft hijacking incident, they **received** more aid and other political considerations than other countries in the region, for years afterwards.

So the answer is: there will never be an end to arm-twisting as long as countries want to interact with the international community. That can be more or less polite, and the issues will change as countries get more interconnected.

Comment: The problem with your answer is that: (1) there is a cartel led by the USA whose interests are similar; (2) this cartel's major ally is India, not Pakistan. Hence, Pakistan is trapped in a position, unlike any other country.

Comment: For example, how are these poor countries going to stop the corrupt politicians from stashing money in  [the tax havens provided by the cartel](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/72142/32479)?

Comment: @user366312, I don't see it that way. Tax havens are a global problem. And pressure is part of any high-stakes negotiation. One sees that where one is affected. As I see it, Pakistan *got away* with things that would have gotten other countries sanctioned because of their help in the Afghanistan conflict.

Comment: *I don't see it that way. Tax havens are a global problem. And the pressure is part of any high-stakes negotiation. One sees where one is affected.* --- Why are so many politically exposed persons from poorer countries living in exile in the UK and the USA? E.g. Nawaz Sharif of Pakistan?

Comment: *As I see it, Pakistan got away with things that would have gotten other countries sanctioned because of their help in the Afghanistan conflict.* --- Like what?

Comment: @user366312, not keeping order in the then-FATA, supporting terrorists in Afghanistan, deals with North Korea and Syria.

Comment: Why are absconder Nawaz Sharif and Altaf Hossain living in the UK?

Comment: @user366312, that question is off-topic. You are trying to turn this into a debate rather than Q&A. There are three answers. One is +1/-1, one is 0/-2, one is 0/-5 and deleted by a moderator.